# Problem with basic linear algebra logic.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a basic problem of basic linear algebra.
It is less about the equation and more about the logic.
The Problem is as follows.

Solve.

$$5 (- 3 x - 2) - (x - 3) = - 4 (4 x + 5) + 13$$

The question I wish to know in relation to logic is as follows

$$-15 x - 10 - x + 3 = - 16 x - 20 + 13$$

Now, when adding up the above equation to get the answer, is it I add the two values with $x$ such as $-15x$ and $x$ so as to get $-16x$? And then do I add the two values without $x$ such as $10$ and $3$? If so, how do I know if I am to add the values or minus the values?
Essentially the question is how, based on the logic, does the above equation equals, as follows

$$-16x - 7 = -16x - 7?$$

Comment: Your calculations are correct. At the end, you can go one step further by collecting the $x$ terms and constant terms (e.g., add $16x+7$ to both sides); you'll end up with $0=0$. This is true for all values of $x$. The left-hand side and right-hand side of the original equation are, in fact, identical.

Comment: It is ok I have solved it, I was not sure if a plus and a minus made a minus or a plus, I have discovered it is a minus and now the logic makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, this is called [combining/collecting like terms](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydefs2.htm). So you have $$-15 x - 10 - x + 3 = - 16 x - 20 + 13$$
$$-15x-x-10+3=-16x-20+13$$
$$-16x-7=-16x-7$$

Now you have to solve for $x$, but clearly it is satisfied for any value of $x$. Adding $7$ to both sides and then dividing by $-16$ we have $$-16x-7=-16x-7$$
$$-16x=-16x$$
$$x=x$$

which is always true.

Comment: Yes thank you, I made an error of comprehending the logic in relation to plus and minus combinations. In linear algebra, is it always the value outside the brackets is to be multiplied by the valeus inside the brackets?

Comment: Yes, when expanding brackets you have $5(x+2)=5x+10$ or $(x+1)(x+2)=x(x+2)+1\cdot(x+2)=x^2+2x+x+2=x^2+3x+2$ for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand algebra completely, it was the logic that had me slightly confused

Comment: It's value, letters and operations with a logic of computation, like all basic computing sytems, once you understand it is just values, letters, and operations goverened by a set of laws, it becomes easy to crack.